# Make a Textfield required when list/menu option is selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery-ui

I want to validate a `textfield` when a relating `dropdown` is selected.
usually it should be allowed to submit `null` but when its relating drop menu is selected `null` should not be allowed.

```
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option value="red">one</option>
  <option value="blue">two</option>
  <option value="green">three</option>
</select>
```

Lets say i select red from the dropdown

```
<input name="red" id="red" type="text">
```

should be required, while others like `<input name="blue" id="blue" type="text"><input name="green" id="green" type="text">` can be sent as null and vice versa.

The text field should serve as a full detail for the option selected so, it should correspend.

Is there a way to handle this with javascript?

Comment: For clarity, if the user selects a colour from the drop down, then the colour that is submitted by the text field must submit the same colour?  I assume you are trying to stop people choosing a select option and then sending you a different colour by text field?

Comment: @Stephen Exactly my goal

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load',function(){ SimpleVal.init(); });
      var SimpleVal = {};
      SimpleVal.init = function(){
        this.form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        this.textInputs = [this.form.elements.namedItem("red"), this.form.elements.namedItem("blue"),this.form.elements.namedItem("green")];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.textInputs.length; i++) this.textInputs[i].disabled = true;
        this.form.elements.namedItem("submit").disabled = true;
        let sel = this.form.elements.namedItem("select");
        this.form.addEventListener("change",function(){
          for(let i = 0; i < this.textInputs.length; i++) this.textInputs[i].disabled = true;
          this.form.elements.namedItem("submit").disabled = true;
          if(sel.value){
            this.form.elements.namedItem(sel.value).disabled = false;
            if(this.form.elements.namedItem(sel.value).value)     this.form.elements.namedItem("submit").disabled = false;
          }
        }.bind(this));

      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id='myForm'>
      <select name='select'>
        <option></option>
        <option value="red">one</option>
        <option value="blue">two</option>
        <option value="green">three</option>
      </select>
      <input name='red' type='text'/>
      <input name='blue' type='text'/>
      <input name='green' type='text'/>
      <input name='submit' type='submit'/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d0ep6z16/

Comment: quick and dirty but is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/yce3Ljpf/1/

```
<select id="colors">
    <option></option>
    <option value="red">one</option>
    <option value="blue">two</option>
    <option value="green">three</option>
</select>

<input name="blue" id="red" type="text" class="color-input">
<input name="blue" id="blue" type="text" class="color-input">
<input name="green" id="green" type="text" class="color-input">

<script>
document.getElementById('colors').addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (this.value.length) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("color-input");
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs.item(i).removeAttribute('required');
    }
    document.getElementById(this.value).setAttribute('required', 'required');
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so I've laid this out so you can see what's happening:

```
<select id="colourSelect" onchange="val()">
    <option value="nothing">Please Choose:</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="colourTextInput" size="50" onkeyup="clearMe()">
<br><br>
<button type="submit">Submit Button</button>
<script>
    function val() {
        d = document.getElementById("colourSelect").value;
        if(d !== "nothing")
        {
            document.getElementById("colourTextInput").value = d;
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('colourTextInput').value = "";
        }
    }
    function clearMe() {
        selectBox = document.getElementById("colourSelect");
        selectBox.selectedIndex = null;
    }
</script>
```

When the value of the dropdown is changed the value in the text box is set to the same as the dropdown.  If they then go to the text field and try to change the colour, it defaults the dropdown back to its default setting, meaning that you can only ever have one or the other.

It could be made cleaner by simply clearing the text field when the dropdown is selected etc, but it gives you something to work with.

https://jsfiddle.net/cx1x2txu/

Comment: .. and perhaps a neater approach would be to have a button on your dropdown for "Custom Colour" that when selected just makes the text box disappear, or become read-only.

Comment: would love to hide the other textfields when the corresponding one is selected that would be a better approach

Comment: Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I should have said "make the text box appear" when custom is selected, not disappear :)

Answer (score 0):

I modified this and got it right. Thanks all

```
<html><html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.addEventListener('load',function(){ SimpleVal.init(); });
      var SimpleVal = {};
      SimpleVal.init = function(){
        this.form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        this.textInputs = [this.form.elements.namedItem("red"), this.form.elements.namedItem("blue"),this.form.elements.namedItem("green")];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.textInputs.length; i++) this.textInputs[i].disabled = true;
        this.form.elements.namedItem("submit").disabled = true;
        let sel = this.form.elements.namedItem("select");
        this.form.addEventListener("change",function(){
          for(let i = 0; i < this.textInputs.length; i++) this.textInputs[i].disabled = true;
          this.form.elements.namedItem("submit").disabled = true;
          if(sel.value){
            this.form.elements.namedItem(sel.value).disabled = false;
            if(this.form.elements.namedItem(sel.value).value)     this.form.elements.namedItem("submit").disabled = false;
          }
        }.bind(this));

      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id='myForm'>
      <select name='select'>
        <option></option>
        <option value="red">one</option>
        <option value="blue">two</option>
        <option value="green">three</option>
      </select>
      <input name='red' type='text'/>
      <input name='blue' type='text'/>
      <input name='green' type='text'/>
      <input name='submit' type='submit'/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```